# parsing a particular tag as array using fast-xml-parser in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, json, xml, parsing

I am using fast-xml-parser for converting xml string to JSON in my code. The problem is in XML I have a tag that contains an array of elements, However when we receive only one element inside this tag, the value inside this tag gets parsed as JSON object rather than JSON Array however when there are more than one values it gets parsed as Array.

Below is the example and output that I receive when there is just one element in tag

```
xmlString = `<Items>
               <Item sn="abcd"/>
            </Items>`
```

Output: `{ Items: { Item: { attributes: [Object] } } }`

Below is the example and output when it contains more than one element

```
xmlString = `<Items>
               <Item sn="abcd"/>
               <Item sn="efgh"/>
             </Items>`
```

Output: `{ Item: [ { attributes: [Object] }, { attributes: [Object] } ] }`

Is there a way to fix it so that every time I receive Item as JSON array rather than JSON object?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser#readme) there is a quite flexible option `arrayMode`:

> When `false`, a tag with single occurrence is parsed as an object but as an array in case of multiple occurences. When `true`, a tag will be parsed as an array always excluding leaf nodes. When `strict`, all the tags will be parsed as array only. When instance of `RegEx`, only tags will be parsed as array that match the regex. When `function` a tag name is passed to the callback that can be checked.

In your case, a simple regular expression would do. Not sure whether it expects `/Items/` or `/Item/` though - but you can surely test this in no time.

Example cases that should lead to `Item` be retrieved as arrays:

```
arrayMode: /Item/
arrayMode: tagName => tagName === 'Item'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that the arryMode is a boolean, when set to true it converts all the complex tags to an array. Can you please share an example of how regular expression can be used in the option to parse only selective tag as an array?

Comment: I tried with three combinations but doesn't seems working. `arrayMode: [/Items/,/Item/]` , `arrayMode: [/Items/]` , `arrayMode: [/Item/]`

Comment: @ShailendraChoudhary I edited the post, `arrayMode` should not be an array itself.

Comment: @stock-overlflaw : Thanks for the solution! The first one didn't fit well for me since there was another tag called 'PackedItems' in my XML that was supposed to be parsed as Object but was getting parsed as an array because of regex, plus I have more than one such tag. I used this `arrayMode: tagName => ['Item', 'Transaction'].includes(tagName)` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you can use camaro to transform the output as well which will make it consistent with what you want

you can rename the fields, shape the output with the template which is based on xpath.

in the example below, you specified that the property `items` of the output is an array, then the output will always be an array

example

```js
var { transform } = require("camaro")

async function main() {
  var xmlString = `<Items>
               <Item sn="abcd"/>
            </Items>`
  var template = {
    items: ['Items/Item', {
        sn: '@sn'
    }]
  }
  var output = await transform(xmlString, template)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4))
}

main()
```

output

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "sn": "abcd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Seems like with Camaro I have to provide all tags in the template. so if there are 1000 more elements (mixed of string and complex values ) I have to include all of them in template. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @ShailendraChoudhary yep. it's a way to shape the output object so we have to write everything we want in the template

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with fast-xml-parse in NodeJs, and at a new version lib I need to make a simple solution for this. It's a simple example to applicated in your code.

```
    const xmlDataStr = `
    <S:Envelope>
        <S:Body>
        <w:body2>
        wow phir se
        </w:body2>
        <S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>`;

const stringOptions = [
  'S:Envelope', 'S:Body', 'w:body2'
]
const options = {
  ignoreAttributes: false,
  isArray: (tagName) => {
    if (stringOptions.includes(tagName)) return true;
  }
};
const parser = new XMLParser(options);
const output = parser.parse(data);

output = {"S:Envelope":[{"S:Body":[{"w:body2":"wow phir se","S:Body":[""]}]}]}
```