How to use fast-xml-parser's arrayMode to parse only one element into JSON Array instead to JSON object
I have the played around with following XML-snippet(contents might not be correct but to highlight my question):
My problem is that if I only have one entry (as in layoutsX) the value inside this tag gets parsed as JSON object rather than JSON Array however when there are more than one values it gets parsed as Array.
<keyboard group="126" id="-11687" name="Untitled" maxout="3">
  <layouts>
    <layout first="0" last="17" mapSet="ANSI" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
    <layout first="10" last="17" mapSet="ANSI" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
  </layouts>
  <layoutsX>
    <layoutX first="10" last="17" mapSet="ANSI" modifiers="Modifiers"/>
  </layoutsX>
</keyboard>


I have looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193928/parsing-a-particular-tag-as-array-using-fast-xml-parser-in-nodejs it says you could use the option arrayMode
Unfortunately this does not work for me.
I use the below code but it still gives me an object for 1 element (layoutsX) and an array of objects for several elements (layouts)
How would I get an array of object no matter if I have 1 or several elements?
  const options = {
    ignoreAttributes: false,
    attributeNamePrefix: '@_',    // to access the attribute
    arrayMode: true
  };

 const xmlFile = readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
 const parser = new XMLParser(options);
 const jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlFile); // get plain Object

 const oneEle:any[] = jsonObj.keyboard.layoutsX
 const twoEle:any[] = jsonObj.keyboard.layouts

 console.log("oneEle",typeof(oneEle),oneEle, oneEle[0],oneEle.length)
 console.log("twoEle",typeof(twoEle),twoEle,twoEle[0], twoEle.length)


it says you could use the option arrayMode - which version of fast-xml-parser are you using?
